# Setting the variables of Solve in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I have an equation `a*x+b=0` for which I have `a` and `b` defined *during execution*. What is the best way I can [solve](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/solve.html) the equation using what I've set for `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are going to have to use num2str() and related functions to build the equation in the string form that solve() requires.  That shouldn't be too difficult should it?

Comment: solve('a * x + b=0', strcat('a=',num2str(a)), strcat('b=',num2str(b)) );

Comment: Thanks @srand, I can never remember syntax so I confine my advice to vague hints.

Comment: Additionally, of course, sprintf which I forgot about: solve('a * x + b=0', sprintf('a=%d',a), sprintf('b=%d',b) )... long day:)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you solve symbolically in terms of a and b, and then replace a and b by their value in the result?